# PySerial and IronPython - get strange error

Tags: ironpython, pyserial

I have a device connected to COM31. And the code that I need to create a serial connection looks very simple

```
port = 31
trex_serial = serial.Serial(port - 1, baudrate=19200, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=1)
```

The foollowing code works when I run it using Python2.6, but when executed by IronPython2.6.1, this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 188, in __init__

  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 236, in setPort

  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\serial\serialcli.py", line 139, in makeDeviceName

  File "c:\Python26\lib\site-packages\serial\serialcli.py", line 17, in device

IndexError: index out of range: 30
```

I am not sure what is going on. PySerial clearly says that it is IronPython compliant.
Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

IronPython is asking .NET what the ports are.  They are enumerated differently.  Most likely you are asking to open a connection that doesn't exist as far as IronPython/.NET is concerned.  To find out the "real" port number, use the following code modified from the pySerial scan examples.  Then use the number next to the listed COM.

```
import serial

def scan():
#scan for available ports. return a list of tuples (num, name)
available = []
for i in range(256):
    try:
        s = serial.Serial(i)
        available.append( (i, s.portstr))
        s.close()   # explicit close 'cause of delayed GC in java
    except serial.SerialException:
        pass
    #You must add this check, otherwise the scan won't complete
    except IndexError as Error:
        pass

for n,s in available:
    print "(%d) %s" % (n,s)

return available
```

The output looks like this for me:

(0) COM9

(1) COM15

(2) COM16

(3) COM1

(4) COM15

Then when you try to open the connection, use the number on the left NOT the actual COMportNumber - 1.  For instance I need to open a connection to COM15, so using the above scan:

```
def IOCardConnect():
try:
    connection = serial.Serial(4, 115200, timeout=1, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE)
    print "Connection Succesful"
    return connection
except serial.SerialException as Error:
    print Error
```

Also, once you are connected, pySerial will expect bytes to write to the connectio, not strings.  So make sure you send like this:

```
#Use the built in bytes function to convert to a bytes array.
connection.write(bytes('Data_To_Send'))
```